# How do I fix my JLabel not appearing in the intended JPanel? (Code utilizes JLayeredPane)

Tags: java, swing

I'm currently doing a GUI project as you can see below. While designing the UI I encountered a problem with my JLabel. It wouldn't appear as soon as I run the program.

```
public class Main extends JFrame {

private JFrame mainFrame;
private JPanel parentPanel;
private JPanel sidePanel;

private JLayeredPane layer;

private JPanel info, tri, sqr, rect, circ;
private JLabel infoTF, triLabel, sqrTF, circTF;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main show = new Main();
}

public Main() {
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Geometric Shapes Computation");


    layer = new JLayeredPane();
    layer.setLayout(null);
    layer.setBounds(0,0,700,600);

    Color standard = new Color (76 ,41, 211);
    Color fg = new Color (204, 204, 204);
    Font items = new Font("Century Gothic", Font.BOLD, 12);


    triLabel = new JLabel("Triangle");
    triLabel.setFont(items);
    triLabel.setBackground(standard);
    triLabel.setForeground(fg);
    triLabel.setVisible(true);

    tri = new JPanel();
    tri.add(triLabel);
    tri.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
    tri.setLayout(null);
    tri.setBounds(0, 215, 200, 70);

    sqr = new JPanel();
    sqr.setBackground(standard);
    sqr.setLayout(null);
    sqr.setBounds(0, 315, 200, 70);

    parentPanel = new JPanel();
    parentPanel.setLayout(null);
    parentPanel.setSize(700, 600);


    sidePanel = new JPanel();
    sidePanel.setLayout(null);
    sidePanel.setBounds(0,0,200, 600);
    sidePanel.setBackground(standard);

    sidePanel.add(tri);

    layer.add(parentPanel, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    layer.add(sidePanel, JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);
    layer.add(tri, JLayeredPane.MODAL_LAYER);

    mainFrame.add(layer);
    mainFrame.setSize(700, 600);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a layered pane? Why are you use null layouts everywhere. Swing was designed to be using with layout managers. How can your frame and layered pane both be (600, 700). A JFrame has a title bar and borders, so its impossible for both to be the same size. The size of your label is (0, 0) so there is nothing to paint. This is why you use layout managers. The layout managers will calculate the size/location so you don't have to.

Comment: I'm fairly new to this topic, I do apologize for the mistakes I made here. Hopefully I'll do better upon accomplishing this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly you are just having issues displaying the label, I was able to show the label by commenting out the tri.setLayout(null);

```
tri = new JPanel();
tri.add(triLabel);
tri.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);
//tri.setLayout(null);
tri.setBounds(0, 215, 200, 70);
```

This was able to display the text for me.  Hopefully, this helps.